# how test for no content, while we have 204 NO CONTENT status, as there is no 'Content-Type' header at all?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

It's easy to test `Content-Type` when having a `200 OK` status:

```
it('should list All permissions on /permissions GET', (done)=> {
    supertest(app)
        .get('/permissions')
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end( (err, res)=> {
            // SOME CODE HERE
            done(err)
        })
})
```

So `.expect('Content-Type', /json/)` does the job for us.
Now when we have a `DELETE` request, we want no content to be returned. A status of `204 NO CONTENT` without any content.

When there is no content, the `Content-Type` does not exist. Should we check for the existence of the `Content-Type` header? How to do that using `supertest`?

Thanks in advance for any help you're able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the generic function-based `expect()` to do a custom assertion if you want to check that a header *doesn't* exist:

```
.expect(function(res) {
  if (res.headers['Content-Type'])
    return new Error('Unexpected content-type!');
})
```

If you want to also check that there is no body:

```
.expect(204, '')
```

Comment: can i have body without content? i mean the second that you typed in the answer will be enough and there is no need to the custom assertion, right?

Answer (score 1):

When you send an [HTTP 204 status code](https://httpstatuses.com/204) back from a server, there should not be any content in the body. Most server implementations, ie. express, restify will not include a Content-Type header for this status code.

For your tests using supertest you should just check the HTTP status code using an expect. 
ie:

`.expect(204)`